# Good revision notes for complex variable and linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, linear-transformations, book-recommendation, complex-integration

Are there any short notes on complex analysis and linear algebra (around 100 pages) with some exercises so I can refresh my mind on these two subjects? Initially, I had my study notes but I lost it due to a flood. Now I am going to graduate school and I wish to do some revision before I go.

I don't mind if the content is dense since I learnt them before.

Comment: Hi there !! You may refer these - [Complex Analysis](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~bdriver/120A-F03/Lecture%20Notes/Fall03-Lecture-Notes.pdf)   and [Linear Algebra](https://mathematics.ku.edu/sites/math.drupal.ku.edu/files/files/LinearAlgebraNotes.pdf)